# How to store images submitted from a form in a temporary hidden input?

Tags: html, image, forms, input, hidden

I need to have two step submission form which accepts multiple images to be uploaded to server. The problem here is I need to have some temporary hidden inputs for storing values from the first step to acquire more info in the second step before the actual submission.
Take a look the following codes.
This is for example, the first step:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="step" value="1" />
Name: <input name="name" value="" type="text" />
Email: <input name="email" value="" type="text" />
Image 1: <input type="file" name="images[]" />
Image 2: <input type="file" name="images[]" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The following will be the second step:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="step" value="2" />
<input name="name" value="<?=$_POST['name'];?>" type="hidden" />
<input name="email" value="<?=$_POST['email'];?>" type="hidden" />

<!-- Here is the problem, how should I store the submitted images for the time being? -->
<input type="file" name="images[]" />
<input type="file" name="images[]" />
<!-- ... -->

Please select a type: 
<select name="type">
<option>Type 1</option>
<option>Type 2</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Please note that this code is just for the sake of clarification and is by no means the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should be stored in $_FILES I think. You can also use move_uploaded_file() for storing the files temporarly. See: [php-manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: I know they are stored in `$_FILES`. I guess one way is to store the images on the server from the beginning and pass their uri around.

Comment: Yes you can save them to a temporary location and then remove them after the upload. It's as easy as that.